# create nameserver hex header

Tags: php, sockets, wireshark, nameservers

I have to make a request to a nameserver. the socketpart is working like a charm, but to create the package I have some problems.

```
$domainname = "google.nl";

$hexdomain = ascii2he($domainname);

$package = "\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b".$hexodmain."\x00\x00\xff\x00\x01";
```

this should be the package i send to the nameserver but the package is not correct. what is the right way to create $package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the name you pass to the nameserver is not dot-separated, but every part of the name is transmitted separately.

Second, you do not send the data converted to hex, but send them directly. The hex (`\x01\x01`) is just the representation.

So you would encode your `google.nl` in the form `"\x06google\x02nl\x00"`, as each of the name parts is preceded by its length, and the last one is succeeded by a `\x00` meaning the empty string - which in turn denotes the end of the names chain.

So in order to remain variable, you should split your domain name into its components and precede each of them with the corresponding length byte.

Something like

```
function domain2dns($domain)
{
    $split = explode(".", $domain);
    $target = ""; // cumulate here
    foreach ($split as $part) {
        // For every $part, prepend one byte denoting its length.
        // strlen($part) is its length which is supposed to be put into one character.
        $target .= chr(strlen($part)).$part;
    }
    return $target . "\x00";
}
```

might be useful to do

```
$domainname = "google.nl";

$dnsdomain = domain2dns($domainname);

$package = "\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" . $dnsdomain . "\x00\xff\x00\x01";
```

Comment: so my package is:
$package = "\x06google\x02nl\x00"

something like that?

Comment: @GertKommer No, I was only referring the "name part" of it. The packet around it must be built up properly. I suppose your `"\x01\x01..."` is chosen with care and thus correct.

Comment: @GertKommer To be more verbose, according to http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/protocols/domain-name-system-dns/160-protocols-dns-query.html, you have an ID of `0x0101`, a standard query and one question. So your packet should be `"\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"."\x06google\x02nl\x00"."\x00\xff\x00\x01"` where the 1st part comes from you, the 2nd one is the host name in the appropriate format and the 3rd one is type and class.

Comment: but the problem is it is not always the same. the domainname is always different, so i need to use variables in the packet. Like this:  "\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x".$domain_lenght$domain"\x"$extension_lenght$extension"\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x01" but this breaks the packet.

Comment: @GertKommer A generic solution might be useful here. See my edit.

Comment: `$domein_full = "google.nl";  
    $explode = explode(".",$domein_full);  
    $domain = $explode['0'];  
    $extension = $explode['1'];  
    print_r($explode);  
    $domain_l = str_pad(strlen($domain),2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);  
    $extension_l = str_pad(strlen($extension), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);`  
    
this is what i had and is doing something similar to you code. the problem is i can't make my packet. that's the whole question about. how do i use my variables in the packet without breaking the packet.

still thanks so far for your effort :)

Comment: @Gert Your solution is restricted to only 2 components. But you could simply use the components you prefer and combine them with mine...

Comment: i only have 2 components the rest is already taken away with another function. i am creating a dns check where you can see if your nameserver is responding or not. same for your mail and a couple of other things. to check if the nameserver is responding i send a packet of a domain to the nameserver with the domain in the packet. the domain i get from a textbox. the only question is: how do i use a var in the packet

Comment: second box was working my packet was wrong. sorry for the trouble