# hex html value as php

Tags: php, html, hex

simply put i want to know why the first echo is giving back \x02 and the second echo doesn't give back something when it is exactly the same. why is the first echo not recognized as hex?

```
$test = "02";
echo "\x".$test;
echo "\x02";
```

hope someone can solve this. has been bothering me for a while

Comment: What's wrong with the [answer provided yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13607014/551093)? From my testing, it seems to do _exactly_ what you're asking here.

Comment: for some reason it doesn't recognize the $hexdomain as a hex code. it is saying it is just HTML. if i echo the hexcode directly et is showing the "decoded" sitebuildnu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is what was posted in my other post about this subject.

Link to question:[create nameserver hex header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606868/create-nameserver-hex-header)

credits go to [glglgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296974/glglgl) :)

sorry for the trouble